# why is parse_url returning fragment?

Tags: php, parse-url

I have the following URL:
http://sub.mysite.com/store/?store=Fine+Ting&storeid=3726&test1=value1&test2=value2

Using `print_r(parse_url($url))` gives me this:

```
Array ( 
  [scheme] => http 
  [host] => sub.mysite.com 
  [path] => /store/ 
  [query] => store=Fine+Ting& 
  [fragment] => 038;storeid=3726&test1=value1&test2=value2 
)
```

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) I should only get `fragment` after the hashmark #.

Why then is `parse_url` returning fragment? Shouldn't that be in `[query]`?

Comment: I don't get a `fragment` element when I use your example: `var_dump(parse_url("http://sub.mysite.com/store/?store=Fine+Ting&storeid=3726&test1=value1&test2=value2"));`. Running php5.3.5

Comment: Works here too. Maybe you have an encoding issue. With the hashmark I see a `#038;` in there, that I cannot see anywhere in your url

Comment: The function I use to return the URL uses Wordpress `esc_url`. This seems to use `htmlentities`. That's why I get the `038;` Thanks to @mAu for seeing this :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a problem with you url, the ampersand is encoded in htmlentities (`&#38;`). Therefore `parse_str` thinks, the fragment is starting there.

Try using [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) before passing the url to `parse_url`.

Comment: Where do you get the url from? Are you doing any processing on it?

Comment: @mAu, thanks. Using `html_entity_decode` solved my issue. I'm using a custom function to return URL. This function uses Wordpress's `esc_url`.

Comment: Yep, that's producing the "error". As the docs state: "Encodes ampersands (&) and single quotes (') as numeric entity references (&#038, &#039)." ([esc_url docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url)).